# Hyperlink to raw text of a file with html

Tags: html, hyperlink

While working on my own personal website, I added a webpage that links to several python files of mine. Here is an example of an  tag I wrote that links to a file called "Client.py" on a index.html page of a directory im working in.

`<a class="col" href="./Client.py" target="_blank"> Client.py </a>`

What was peculiar about this was that in some instances it would link to raw text when used locally (such as opening up the html file manually), but when used on a server (Such as using my domain or using live preview), it would download when I click the link, even if there was no download attribute in place.

How can I make this  tag always link to the raw text of a file in every instance instead of downloading it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with html, but with your http server. Please specify what http server you are using (Apache, nginx, ...) so we can give you more specific instructions.

Comment: Im using github.io to store my files, and cloudflare to host my domain.

Answer (score 1):

Python is not configured on your server/localhost. You should run the page on the server which supports Python.

Comment: I use github io to store my files, and cloudflare to host my domain, what can I do in either to configure python/cpp/other files when I need to? @Rajinweb